# Does GM.setClipboard support line breaks?

Tags: javascript, node.js, greasemonkey, tampermonkey

I'm trying to copy some text and set it to the user's clipboard, but I want it to be a list. Yet everything I add to just makes it part of the string (ie. GM.setClipboard("hello\n"goodbye") = "hello\n"goodbye"). I want:

hello
goodbye

Are line breaks supported?

Comment: Try \r\n instead of \n

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per the comment from wOxxOm:

```
\r\n
```